# Cant get javascript addition operator to add correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, operators

I have a button that every time I click it I want it to add 5 to the data attribute.  I am having some trouble figuring this out for some reason.  I have tried several different things but nothing seems to work for me.

```
var i = 5;
$(this).attr('data-count', ++i);
```

but this only fires once for some reason if I click on it it will put the data attribute to 6 but if I click on it again it will stay at 6.

Then I have tried the normal javascript add operator but for it doesn't act correctly.

```
var x = 5;
var y = count;
var newcount = x + y;
$(this).attr('data-count', newcount);
```

The output for this is 50 and then clicking it again is 550 and so on.

I am sure I am missing something but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would really like the first example to work as I would like to count up because I am adding to an existing list as my full code is below.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#showButton", function() {
    var q = $(this).attr('data-q');
    var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var count = $(this).attr('data-count');
    $(this).text('More');
    var i = 5;
    $(this).attr('data-count', ++i);
    $.ajax({ 
       dataType: 'html',
       data: '',
       type: 'POST',
       url : '',
       success: function(response) {
          $('#responseContainer').append(response);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Because every time you click it, it sets the value to 5, then increments it. Set `i` to the current value.

Comment: The problem is hardly caused by JavaScript's addition operator. You initialize `i` to 5 every time, and then overwrite whatever value is in `data-count` with `++i`, which is *always 6*. Of course it stays 6 every time, you explicitly overwrite the previous `6` with a new `6`. I'm curious how you could possibly walk through that code and think any other value *except* 6 could ever be assigned. The `var i = 5` line runs each time, not just once.

Comment: `var i = Number($(this).attr('data-count')) || 5;`

Comment: Thanks Digital Chris I changed the code to var i = count;  $(this).attr('data-count', ++i + 5);  If you want to post this as an answer I wil check it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. "issue"
   init: `$this.data('count', 0)`
   onclick: `$this=$(this);$this.data('count', $this.data('count')+5)`
2. "issue"
   `newcount = x++y`

The reason is that y is a string, when you use `attr` instead of `data`...

A hint: you can use an object as data, e.g.:
`$(this).data('prop', {count:0});$(this).data('prop').count+=5;`

Answer (score 0):

Few things to remember,

**a.** `jquery` identifies attributes starting with `data`, so in order to extract it, you can simply use `.data('attr')` instead of `.attr('data-attr')`.
**b.** In order to increment a value, you need to append it to its existing value so you would need : `$(this).data('count', $(this).data('count') + (++i));`.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#showButton", function() {
    var count = $(this).data('count');
    $(this).text('More');
    var i = 5;
    $(this).data('count', $(this).data('count') + (++i));
    alert($(this).data('count'));
    });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1e0fvkng/